# AndroidTV testing

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

Is it possible to record d-pad keys with Espresso test recorder for AndroidTV testing? 
So far I've tried with Espresso as well as other testing tools such as Appium, UiAutomator, Calabash and Robotium but I couldn't record d-pad keys.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue was already raised to Google back in 2016 (refer [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121205)).

And they specifically said,

> "As of now, Espresso Test Recorder does not specifically support
>   Android TV."

It's already 2019 and seems like they are still not supporting it. I'm also looking for a way for Android TV app automated testing. Please share if you've found any solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I find a solution I will certainly share it.